# Concepts about Local and Global Variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, global, local

please check the code below.

```
x = 10
z = 30
def Rohan():
    y = 15
    x = 20
    print(x,y,z)
    global z
    global x
    z += 5
    print (x,y,z)
Rohan()
```

While calling Rohan(), I am getting an error that reads "SyntaxError: name 'z' is used prior to global declaration
"

Please help me with the concepts of Global Variables and Local variables and what's causing the error.

Comment: You try to use `z` before the `global` declaration, which is not allowed.

Comment: That's exactly what the error message says.  Right?  I'm not sure how it could have been clearer.

Comment: You have already used the global value of `z` in `print(x,y,z)` (Line #7) and then you are trying to declare `global z`, which is not allowed and giving the error. Declare `global z` and `global x` at the start of the function to remove the errors.